# Matlab Taylor series for e^x transforming to 1/e^x?

Tags: matlab, taylor-series

I'm trying to make the code below work by modifying it so that e^-x will work, essentially I'm trying to modify it so that e^-x is 1/e^x 
I'm really not sure how to do that..Here is my code..

```
function [result] = eTaylor(x, n) 
% approximate e^x 
% using first n non-zero terms of the Taylor series 
% e^x = 1 + x + x^2/(2!) + x^3/(3!) + x^4/(4!) + ... 
% Input arguments: 
% x = real argument to function e^x 
% n = number of non-zero terms of Taylor series 
result = 0.0; term = 1.0; 
for i = 1:1:n 
result = result + term; 
term = term*x/i; 
end
```

Comment: Are you using a Taylor expansion because you are studying sequences and series, or for speed?

Answer (score 4):

To get `1/e^x` you simply need to compute `e^(-x)`. supply your `eTaylor` function with `-x` instead of `x` and you are done!

```
 oneOverExp = eTaylor( -x, n );
```

PS,
It is best [not to use `i` as a variable name in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).